# Having trouble with private routing using firebase auth and email verification. How do I fix these routes?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I fix my private route to account for the emailVerification page?

Currently, if currentUser.user and currentUser.isVerified it will route to the home page, else it will route to the login page.

The problem, If currentUser.user is true and currentUser.isVerified is false, I want it to route to /emailVerification, not login. And then once currentUser.isVerified is also true, I want it to route to the home page.

Been stuck on this for a couple days any help is appreciated.

PrivateRoute.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useAuth } from '../Contexts/AuthContext';

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  console.log(currentUser, 'here');

  return (
    <Route {...rest}>
      {currentUser.user && currentUser.isVerified ? children : <Redirect to="/login" />}
    </Route>
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  children: propTypes.node.isRequired,
};
```

App.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from './Contexts/AuthContext';
import GridContainer, { Container, Row, Col } from './Components/Grid';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Login from './Pages/Authentication/Login';
import Signup from './Pages/Authentication/Signup';
import ForgotPassword from './Pages/Authentication/ForgotPassword';
import EmailVerification from './Pages/Authentication/EmailVerification';
import Tabs from './Components/Tabs';
import Dashboard from './Pages/Portal/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './Components/PrivateRoute';
import Home from './Pages/Home';

const App = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = false;
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Container>
        {!isAuthenticated ? (
          <Row>
            <Col lg={12}>
              <Navbar />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ) : null}

        <Router>
          <Col lg={12}>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute path="/home">
                <Home />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <Route path="/login">
                <Login />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/signup">
                <Signup />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/emailVerification">
                <EmailVerification />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/forgotPassword">
                <ForgotPassword />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/">
                <Login />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Col>
        </Router>
      </Container>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite te code to something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import propTypes from "prop-types";
import { useAuth } from "../Contexts/AuthContext";

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  console.log(currentUser, "here");

  if (currentUser.user && !currentUser.isVerified) {
    <Route {...rest}>
      {currentUser.user && currentUser.isVerified ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/emailVerification" />
      )}
    </Route>;
  } else {
    return (
      <Route {...rest}>
        {currentUser.user && currentUser.isVerified ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )}
      </Route>
    );
  }
};

export default PrivateRoute;

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  children: propTypes.node.isRequired,
};
```